# Parsing XML data with ElementTree (NONE or no data)

Tags: python, elementtree

I am stuck with parsing XML data from URL (API). I get data from API and if do `print(bookings_data)` I get all data from the XML file. Also, I can get tag results out as well but once when I try to get data in text format I get nothing or NONE result.

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://vatbook.euroutepro.com/xml2.php?fir=LQSB'
response = requests.get(url)
bookings_data = response.text
root = ET.fromstring(bookings_data)

for atcs in root.iter('booking'):
   for callsign_tag in atcs.find("callsign"):
      print (callsign_tag.text)
```

Now when I run this code I got nothing at all and I tried a bunch of different configurations from findall, get and still no results (or I get NONE).

What might be wrong here?

Here is URL of an XML file: http://vatbook.euroutepro.com/xml2.php?fir=LQSB
(In this URL you could use XML or XML2, I get same data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements, `Element.find` returns the first child with a particular tag. In other words, it returns an Element, not an iterable, meaning you cannot use a for loop to access it.

```
for atcs in root.iter('booking'):
    print (atcs.find('callsign').text)
```